# Is there a course in audio format for learning Esperanto from scratch?

Tags: learning, resources

Is there an audio course, that busy people can use to learn Esperanto from scratch from anywhere? I am looking for something like [Coffee Break Spanish](https://radiolingua.com/coffeebreakspanish/), where a speaker uses a start language (here English) to teach a goal language (here Spanish). As the episodes go on, more and more words are in the goal language instead of the start language.

Comment: Coffee break Spanish and French are awesome! I have so far mostly seen books and a few video courses for Esperanto. I've been listening to a bit of the Esperanto teacher as an audio book, but that doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 4):

The Assimil Esperanto course is an audio-based course, albeit with an accompanying handbook which I think is only in French. It's available via Amazon for €39: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B00008CTCE

Comment: Just to clarify: Can you use Assimil as a complete audio-only course? The Coffee Break series is really great, really detailed. It takes you by the hand from zero to decent. In the beginning of the Spanish course, they spend like a third of an episode learning how to pronounce "muy" correctly. Something as engaging for Esperanto would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea. I can't say that I have ever heard of such a course. The closest I have in my collection is *Flugu kun Petro* - a rather "home made" looking course for children that includes crude recordings of the text in the book.

A quick Google search turned up this blog post which recommends *Jen Nia Mondo*.

https://www.esperanto-usa.org/en/node/405

The above link also mentions a course by Sylvan Zaft in podcast format, but the link was broken and I was unable to locate it.